# full path of the process running on a windows

Tags: windows, command

Is there any command in windows which can give full path of the process running 
`tasklist` does not give full paths. I do not want to use `task manager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`tlist`](http://ss64.com/nt/tlist.html) tool is not distributed with the Windows Resource Kit anymore (it's been superseded by `tasklist`), but is able to list the full path of each process.

You can fetch a copy from the [download center](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19879).

Answer (score 0):

Now can do it using powershell:

```
PS C:\> gwmi win32_process | select CommandLine | select-string -pattern "process-name"
```